# Load view without refreshing the page

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, subdomain, pushstate, states

I am running angular 1.5 spa application with angular-ui-router, where I load states as the user clicks on links. My application has subdomains like subdomain.domain.com. What I want is to load a state across the subdomains. Like if I am on a state subdomain**1**.domain.com/view/view1 and has to go to subdomain**2**.domain.com/view/view2, can there be a possibility to load the state without having to reload the whole angular app. I saw something like $window.history.pushState, but that does not work with subdomains. All the different subdomains use the same piece of angular code, means all the subdomains are pointing to the same server (managed through AWS)

Comment: have you looked into iframes and the messaging api between a parent and child api?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Comment: I want every domain without refreshing too, and pass me some cookies together.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not related to angularjs, when you go to subdomain2.domain.com you are going to a whole different web domain, it's not different from going to www.google.com, so angular can't treat it like a sub-page navigation in the same domain.

I think a similar effect may be achieved using templateUrl's though, just put your needed view templates on second domain address like:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute'])

.config(function($routeProvider){
  $routeProvider.when("/something",
    {
      templateUrl: "http://subdomain1.domain.com/view/view1.html",
      controller: "AppCtrl1"
    }   
  ).when("/somethingElse", 
    {
      templateUrl: "http://subdomain2.domain.com/view/view2.html",
      controller: "AppCtrl2"
    };
})
```

But the main app still resides on the same domain.

Comment: Thanks Reek for the quick response. Let me tell you my use case. I want to create a sub-domain for each user who signs up on my portal. Like  userid1.domain.com, userid2.domain.com... The solution you are proposing, to me it looks like the templates will be stored on a subdomain, while the app / views will loaded on a single domain. What I want is to show the url in the browser address bar as http://userid1.domain.com, userid2.domain.com. The routes will be same for all the subdomains, just that they load the data for different users. Please accept my apologies if I misunderstood your solution

Comment: Then I suppose you could use a servlet filter in java (or whatever the equivalent is in your server side architecture) to understand which domain the request originated from (userid1 or 2), and return appropriate user data to client side.

Comment: On the server side, I am able to get the correct data. I have only 2 requirements: 1) To have subdomains for the users, which is working as well 2) To NOT reload the whole angular app as the user moves from userid1.domain.com to userid2.domain.com